# Cronjob to have headline for the results

Tags: cron

I have a cronjob that finds a text string in files then sends the list of results via email.
I would like to insert a headline that describe the type of results just above the list:
(Headline is just above the results and not as the email's subject)

```
**Headeline goes here**

/usr/www/users/xyz/wp-admin/file1.php
/usr/www/users/xyz/wp-admin/file2.php
/usr/www/users/xyz/wp-admin/file3.php
/usr/www/users/xyz/wp-admin/file4.php
```

How this can be done?

Thanks for the help,
Amit.

Comment: Please provide your script. W/o it we can't help

Comment: It's just a simple, ordinary find script:

    grep -irl 'text-to-find' /usr/www/users/myusername/* | mail -s "files list" amit@mywebsite.com

I need the headline above the list